# Push reports generated by Chef-compliance, into chef-automate

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I have both chef-compliance standalone server installed and also have another chef-automate instance.

I'm running compliance scans for group of nodes from chef-compliance.

Question how do I push my compliance test reports int chef-automate?

Comment: I won't bother copying over my disclaimer from last time, but same thing, hopefully you've already emailed Chef Software support.

Comment: @coderanger yes I already did. but I don't get past response yet. may be still I'm evaluating this at trial period. just wanted to check if anyone use chef automate and having this kind of questions.  thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no use of chef-compliance anymore., it has been replaced by chef-automate. chef-automate version 1.7.39 upper version, you get access for scanner option.